# What response code Apache throws when it max out?

Tags: apache, web, http-status

I use Apache 2.4 as web server. When it exceeds max connections limit, what response code the client receives from the web server?

Answer (score 1):

Apache throws 504 status code response to client.

**504 GATEWAY TIMEOUT**

The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response from an upstream server it needed to access in order to complete the request.

Comment: Thanks Nitin. I receive status code 502 when my requests are not able to hit Apache. What could be the possible cause of getting 502?

Comment: provide the complete message with status code, timeout or proxy

Comment: I receive below 502 errors on proxy server:

1. "upstream prematurely
closed connection while reading response header from upstream,"

2. "upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream"